# the condition of if and else are false and its jump to else directly and my data are true

Tags: php, laravel

```
        $reqAmount = $service->price;
        $useraa = auth()->user();
        //$usersRl = DB::table('gift_card_services')->select('id')->get();
        $usersDay1 = DB::table('gift_card_services')->select('created_at')->where('id',1)->get();
        $usersDay4 = DB::table('gift_card_services')->select('created_at')->where('id',4)->get();
        $usersDay7 = DB::table('gift_card_services')->select('created_at')->where('id',7)->get();
        if ($useraa->username == "abdoumadris") {
            // $reqAmount = ($service->price - 2);
            if ($usersDay1 == "2022-10-07 19:56:20" ) {
                $reqAmount = ($service->price - 2);
            }
            else if ($usersDay4 == "2022-10-07 19:57:20") {
                $reqAmount = ($service->price - 6);
            }
            else if ($usersDay7 == "2022-10-07 19:59:00") {
                $reqAmount = ($service->price - 10);
            }else{
                $reqAmount = ($service->price - 1);
            }
        }
```

i need to change the price for all product but its allways - 1

i am sure 100% that my data are set correctly and the if condition is true, but it's override to else directly

Comment: `var_dump($usersDay1)` and al the other variables you want to check. What is inside them?

Comment: Maybe check out [Laravel Get Method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-get) and try `->get('created_at')` instead an empty get()

Comment: _"i am sure 100% that my data are set correctly"_ - and I am (almost) a 100% sure that you did not actually _verify_ this, but are working based on mere assumptions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to work with date/time. What you are comparing is a special string representation of format 'Y-m-d H:i:s'. You should check if these dates are really also stored like that in the database. This is not the way I would expect date/time to be stored.

Please give a dump of $usersDay1, $usersDay4 and $usersDay7. If these are timestamps, you might need to bring them to a different format before comparing them to string representations.

Comment: I downvoted your answer, as it is more a comment and not yet an answer. Please read the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - btw. if your read the comments, it is already mentioned, that he should share the dump of the variables. :) He is probably comparing against a Laravel collection and not a String.

Comment: If I could have commented, I would have done that. I jumped into this rather quickly. There were no comments when I started to reply. Thank you for your understanding.